# Not able to append values into the data class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to download data from Firestore and add it to a POJO class but when I use to add all functions all the previous elements are removed from the list only one element remains every time I want to append values into the list.

My Code:

```
  db.collection("Posts").document(postId).collection("Groups")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    Log.d(myTAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
                    arr.add(document.id)

                        Log.d(myTAG, "Documents are  $document")
                        db.collection("Users")
                            .whereEqualTo("id", document.id)
                            .get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener {
                                if (it.isSuccessful){
                                    val objects2: List<Users> = it.result?.toObjects(Users::class.java) as List<Users>
                                    val list2 = mutableListOf<Users>()
                                    list2.addAll(objects2)
                                    userList.value = list2
                                    Log.d(myTAG," list size "+ list2.size.toString())


                                }
                            }

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d(myTAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I use add all function all the previous elements are removed from the list only one element remains every time

This is happening because are creating a new mutable list at every iteration in your for-loop. You should only create a single instance. So to solve this, please move the following line of code:

```
val list2 = mutableListOf<Users>()
```

Right before the line where the for-loop starts:

```
for (document in result) { ... }
```